# Como filtrar uma lista de forma assíncrona usando LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, async

Exemplo de código sem o uso do async:

```
var products = db.Products.Where(_ => _.UserId == currentUserId);
```

Como faço para tornar essa consulta assíncrona levando em conta que o `Where` do `Linq` não suporta o uso do `await`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O truque está na hora de compôr a lista:

```
var products = await db.Products.Where(_ => _.UserId == currentUserId).ToListAsync();
```

Veja todos os métodos assíncronos [por este link aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn176283(v=vs.113).aspx).

Answer (score 7):

O método `Where` constrói um objeto que representa uma query a ser executada, sendo que nenhuma query foi executada ainda. Por isso **não faz sentido que o método `Where` seja executado assincronamente**.

O que você deve estar procurando é a execução assíncrona do método que executa de fato a query. Diz-se que estes métodos materializam a query. Um exemplo é o método `ToList`, que transforma o objeto que representa a query em uma lista de objetos materializados.

O método **`ToList` possui uma versão que pode ser chamada assincronamente: [`ToListAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync(v=vs.113).aspx)**, que permite o uso da palavra chave `async` o que fará a materialização dos objetos de forma assíncrona.

```
// criando objeto que representa uma query, mas que não executa a mesma
var productsQuery = db.Products.Where(_ => _.UserId == currentUserId);

// materializando a query, ou seja, obtendo os resultados, de forma assíncrona
var products = await productsQuery.ToListAsync();
```

A título de informação suplementar, também é possível fazer isso na hora de salvar os dados. O método `SaveChanges` possui também um alter-ego assíncrono [`SaveChangesAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechangesasync(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
// salvando as alterações feitas no context
db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: @Fernando: adicionei exemplos como você sugeriu.